# Sortings stocks into quantiles based on their signal

Tags: python, performance, numpy, statistics, pandas

This function sorts stocks into quantiles.
To do so I used this function that accepts `sig_df` (dataframe with the timeseries of stocks signal) and number of quantiles as imput:

```
qs = ['Q' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(perc)+1)]
q_labels= list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
itertools.repeat(x, int(sig_df.shape[1]/q_num)) for x in qs))

rank_labels = ['rank_{}'.format(i) for i in range(sig_df.shape[1])]

bucketed_names = pd.DataFrame(
        sig_df.columns.values[np.argsort(-sig_df.values, axis=1)], 
        columns=[q_labels, rank_labels]
        )
```

The second function computes portfolio returns, based on the names bucketed in the function above. It accepts two input a `ret_df` containing stocks return and the output from the function above. To do so I used:

```
bucketed_returns = dict()
for i in range(1, int(ret_df.shape[1]/bucketed_names.Q1.shape[1])):
    Q = [] 
    for row in bucketed_names['Q' + str(i)].itertuples():
        temp = ret_df.loc[list(row[:1]) ,list(row[1:])]
        Q.append(float(np.dot(temp, weights)))
        bucketed_returns['Q' + str(i)] = Q          
bucketed_returns = pd.DataFrame(bucketed_returns)
```

To optimize this code I thought about multiprocessing — but as a beginner I don't know how — or maybe there could be a better way remaining in pandas/numpy environment.

Comment: Why aren't you able to code multiprocessing?

Comment: I am a beginner and the libraries online are not so clear